# how to insert variables in associative array using for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, associative-array

I want to insert two values in an associative array one for the key and second for the value and as i print that array it should contain all a-k as keys and 0-10 as their corresponding values.

```
<?php
$z=array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k");

$countsub1 = array();
for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)
{

$countsub1 = array("$z[$i]","$i");

}
print_r($countsub1);

?>
```

Here, I get only last value of variables in array but i want all of them in one. How this can be done??

i want this **Output:**

Array ( [a] => 0,[b] => 1,[c] => 2,[d] => 3,[e] => 4,[f] => 5..........so on )

Comment: Why are so many people answering this question and not looking at the OP question... It's asking for associative array, use any answer below just change it to array($z[$i] => $i) instead of the comma.

Comment: no one is getting it i want results like Array ( [a] => 0,[b] => 1,[c] => 2,[d] => 3,[e] => 4,[f] => 5..........so on )

Comment: What about a simple array_flip()? It flips the keys with the values.

Comment: @KrisztiánDudás the point the OP is making is that many of the answers are incorrect and an array_flip doesn't change the way it is currently done

Comment: I just simply want a-k as keys and 0-10 as their corresponding values @KrisztiánDudás Dudás

Comment: sorry , but you update your desired output after our answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a single line you can use **[array_flip()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)** PHP function.

```
$countsub1 = array_flip($z);
```

OR

```
$z=array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k");    
$countsub1 = array();
for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)
{
   $countsub1[$z[$i]] = $i;
}
print_r($countsub1);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [a] => 0
    [b] => 1
    [c] => 2
    [d] => 3
    [e] => 4
    [f] => 5
    [g] => 6
    [h] => 7
    [i] => 8
    [j] => 9
    [k] => 10
)
```

Comment: great work mr. Sadikhasan  , this is exactly what i was looking for thank you @Sadikhasan

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing it to `array`. You are storing it to a `variable`. Thats why it is overwriting the last value and you are getting the last one. Try with -

```
$countsub1[] = array("$z[$i]","$i");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$z=array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k");

$countsub1 = array();
for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++) {
    $countsub1[] = array($z[$i],$i);
}
print_r($countsub1);
?>
```

You have to put assign values to array with `$countsub1[]` as `$countsub1` will overwrite the previous one on each loop.

PS: variables should not be placed inside the quotes like you did inside the loop while assigning, PHP may consider it as strings

Comment: Please leave the comment if you are downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

You keep overriding `$countsub1`, which is why you only get the last value.

You need to append it onto the array by using one of the following methods:

```
$countsub1[] = array("$z[$i]","$i"); 
array_push($countsub1, array("$z[$i]","$i"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for making an associative array like the OP is asking for:
Code below will work if you want duplicate keys, if not I'd recommend doing an array merge

```
$z=array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k");

$countsub1 = array();
for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)
{
   //duplicate keys option
   $countsub1[] = array($z[$i] => $i);
    //single array with unique keys
   $countsub1 = array_merge($countsub1, array($z[$i] => $i));
}
print_r($countsub1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $arr=array();
    for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++){
        $key =$z[i];
        $arr[$key]=$i;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Like other said, you keep assigning to `$countsub1` so it is overwritten and have the value of the last assignment. You need to **append** to it instead.

So what you want to do is to flip the keys and values of `$z` array, right? If so, there is already a predefined function for you: [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

EDIT: and if you want to do it manually, I suggest below more flexible code which accept varying length of `$z`:

```
$countsub1 = array();
foreach ($z as $key => $value) {
    $counsub1[$value] = $key;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

in your code you are assigning the values to the variable hens it is picking up the last value if you want to insert the values into the array use like this

```
 $array=array()
    for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)
    {

    $array[] = array($z[$i],$i);

    }

    print_r($array)

$array[] is the method to insert values into the array.and $array  is the method to assign value to variable . 
that's the reason you are getting only last value as it is overwriting the previous value.

$array[] will store the values into the index like "0,1,2....."
$array will override the values every time in the loop
if you use $array['key'] in the loop it will also do the same job as $array
```